# Proving a certain subset is closed in $L^1$

Tags: banach-spaces, lp-spaces

In an exam, I was asked to prove that, if $A=\{f\in L^1([0,1]):\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x\leq1\}$, then $A$ is closed in $L^1$. I tried this approach. $A$ is closed iff for all $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ with $f_n\in A$ for all $n$, then $f\in A$. So let us take such a sequence $f_n$ and its limit $f$. We have to show $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x\leq1$. We could try:
$$\|f\|^2\leq\|f-f_n\|^2+\|f_n\|^2\leq1+\|f-f_n\|^2,$$
but then we would need to prove the first term tends to zero, which would be true were this the $L^1$ norm, but it is the $L^2$ norm, and convergence in $L^1$ does not necessarily imply convergence in $L^2$ AFAIK. I guess the condition that $\|f_n\|^2\leq1$ could tell me more, but I can't see how. Surely I can't deduce a dominated convergence, because the monotony of the integral is not invertible, so the fact $\int_0^1|f_n(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_0^11^2\mathrm{d}x=1$ doesn't imply the $|f_n|$s are no greater than one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Poor Fatou, always forgotten...

Comment: So we have a subsuccession $f_{n_k}$ which converges poitwise almost everywhere to $f$, and by Fatou:
$$\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\liminf_{k\to\infty}|f_{n_k}(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leq\liminf_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1|f_{n_k}(x)|\mathrm{d}x\leq1,$$
right? Then I agree: poor Fatou, so loathed and always forgotten - in fact, always forgotten and therefore so loathed :).

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @DavidMitra if you convert these comments to an answer I will accept it :). Just to get this off the unanswered list :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$(f_n)$ has a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ that coverges to $f$ a.e.. Note $f^2_{n_k}\buildrel{k\rightarrow\infty}\over\longrightarrow f^2$ a.e., and apply [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma) to $(f^2_{n_k})$.